# Shadowbox doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, shadowbox

I have an XHTML 1.0 Strict document in which I'm trying to make Shadowbox work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Test page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shadowbox.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="shadowbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      Shadowbox.init();
      console.log('Howdy there!'); // displays, so no JS error in Shadowbox.init
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <a href="image.jpg" title="Howdy" rel="shadowbox">
        <img src="image.jpg" alt="Click to zoom." />
      </a>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

This document is completely valid according to my Firefox extension.

For some reason Shadowbox seems to do *nothing*. When I click the image link, the browser just opens the image as usual. No box at all.

I've tried not loading JQuery and only load Shadowbox but that didn't help, so it's not JQuery's fault either. This is with Shadowbox 3.0b by the way. Any ideas?

EDIT: I just got thinking... Shadowbox does some internal magic to figure out the path to it. However, this page is completely static and loaded directly from file on disk. Could this be the problem? Looking in the DOM, I see that Shadowbox.path is correctly set to "file:///C:/..." so maybe not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have (nebo have to have) all directories from showbox.zip in the directory with the file showbox.js, because showbox adds other scripts to the page.